# Sticky Nav doesn't follow into next container on page

Tags: bootstrap-4

My sticky nav works while it is in its own "container-fluid". However, when it hits the next container fluid (jumbotron), it hits it perfectly like it's a brick wall and stays there. I know it's a container issue because it is sticky on the image slider section. It doesn't hit the wall until the jumbotron. How can I make it extend into all the other containers on the page?

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
<div class="container-fluid"><!--takes up 100% of screen-->
 <!--brand is for logo-->
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img id="navLogo" src="logo-dark.jpg"></a>
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
  <!--ml-auto explands the nav on larger screens-->
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
   <!--active class shows what page you are on-->
   <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Gallery</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Services</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Contact</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>

</div>
 
</nav>

<!--- Image Slider -->
<div id="slides" class="carousel slides" data-ride="carousel">
 <ul class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="1"></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
   <img src="hold-hands2.png">
   <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h1 class="display-2">Elixer Hair Studio</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
   <img src="groupOut2.png">
   <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h1 class="display-2">Elixer Hair Studio</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<!--- Jumbotron -->
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row jumbotron">
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tried about an hour of stuff and here was what worked:

1. Wrap the entire nav in a header tag
2. Take sticky-top class off of the nav and move it to the header tag
   This still wasn't working, so I added the following:
3. In the CSS, add this to the .sticky-top rule

   .sticky-top {
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
   }